# Trivial cases of a Theorem of Criterion for Multiple Zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis

This is from Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*:

> Theorem: A polynomial $f(x)$ over a field $F$ has a multiple zero in
> some extension E if and only if $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have a common
> factor of positive degree in $F[x]$.

Counterexample: For case $f(x)=0$ the zero function with $F=\mathbb{R}$, it has a multiple zero on $x=4$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $E=\mathbb{R}$ but $f(x)=f'(x)=0$ have no common factor of positive degree in $F[x]$.

I just want to know if the criterion doesn't apply for trivial cases or why is my counterexample wrong.

Comment: Is the counterexample yours, or is that from the book? Maybe an exercise?

Comment: The counterexample is mine. It is supposed to be wrong because the book state the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample doesn't work.

In fact, we have for example $g(x)=x^2$ that it is common factor of $f(x)=f'(x)=0$ because $x^2*b=f(x)=f'(x)$ with $b=0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
What's more, every polynomial in $F[x]$ is $gcd(0,0)$.

I wish I helped.

Comment: Indeed, every polynomial is a factor of the zero polynomial.